# full path url is showing when run my application

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-security

I use spring security on the level authentifiaction for my application.
My problem is that `http://localhost:8080/Test/login.jsf;jsessionid =10FAC2C225E786F074342A1824417BCE` figure  when I run my application I do not know why

it was simply `http://localhost:8080/Test/login.jsf`
from which it comes?

Answer (score 1):

JSESSIONID is a cookie generated by a Servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty and used for session management in a Java EE web application for the http protocol.

You can read more details on this [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/08/what-is-jsessionid-in-j2ee-web.html)

If you are using Tomcat 7, you can add the following in the session config to remove jsession id from the URL.

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

Comment: thank you @Vikas V .I add this configuration like you say in web.xml    but a got this HTTP Status 404 - / Test/

-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------

Type Report'' state

Post / Test/

No description The requested resource is not available''.

Comment: Which application server you are using? Is it Tomcat 7? 404 indicates that your web application (Test) is not available for use yet(not properly deployed or something)

Comment: Tomcat 7.0.39 when I remove the seeion configuration it works fine